# How do I make a variable that has its values pre-edited at declaration?

Tags: c++, variables

I want to make a normalized coordinate system and I was wondering if there was a way to make a variable that will do this on declaration:

```
Normals.BottomLeftX *= ClientArea.right;
Normals.BottomRightX *= ClientArea.right;
Normals.TopLeftX *= ClientArea.right;
Normals.TopRightX *= ClientArea.right;

Normals.BottomLeftY *= ClientArea.bottom;
Normals.BottomRightY *= ClientArea.bottom;
Normals.TopLeftY *= ClientArea.bottom;
Normals.TopRightY *= ClientArea.bottom;
```

p.s. I plan to make an X and Y version of each.The values are arbitrary. If the value is for x it will be multiplied by the right value as the y is multiplied by the bottom value. To get a better understanding of what it needs to do, I will be using it to create sections in a gui game engine.

Comment: Do you have a structure (or class) named `Normals` or is `Normals` an _instance_ of a structure/class?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Do member variables of the Normals (struct?) have a predefined initial value, which you want to multiply by client area dimensions in the constructor of the Normals?

Comment: Normals is a struct. All the variables in it are in this. They are the declared values

Comment: If `Normals` is an actual structure (and not an instance), you can add a constructor to it. In C++ the only difference between a structure and a class is the default visibility (`public` for `struct`, `private` for `class`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always just write a constructor for `Normals.foo` that takes in `ClientArea.bar` then sets the value of itself to itself times `ClientArea.bar`.

But then every member of Normals would have to be a type of class or struct you made. I think it would be better just to do something like what you have there unless the ClientArea changes frequently in your program.